# Is my question off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, recommendation-questions

Not even sure what to title this post and what I've chosen seems to be overused but still seems appropriate.

I asked this question 2 years ago:
[What is a simple framework for time testing pandas and numpy related solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44467828/2336654)

Because I was often cobbling together benchmarks for various solutions to a pandas question.  Very often the askers of pandas questions are dealing with large amounts of data and speed/efficiency becomes an issue.  I understand that we have a model on how good questions are to be presented.  Consequently, I've described my problem.  I've provided the means to reproduce the situation.  But I didn't provide my own attempt... in the question.  I did, however, provide my own attempt in a separately posted answer.

Recently, one of the answerers posted a second answer in which they provided two library solutions.  One library was their own and the other was not.  I decided to put a bounty on to reward that answer because I thought it was worthy.  However, before I was able to award that bounty @MartijnPieters closed this question as off-topic.

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Martijn Pieters

I'm not sure if my phrasing of the question requesting a 'framework' led to any misunderstandings but the question was asking how others would concisely measure performance of various pandas/numpy solutions.

It is my strong opinion that this question and these answers add value to the site.  My question to the rest of you is, do you agree that this is off-topic?  If so, can it be salvaged such that you would no longer think it was off-topic?

As usual, I'm open to accept the community's will.

Comment: Given your question "Is there a simple framework to get a fairly comprehensive view into how fast various solutions are?": Yes, your question asks for a recommendation of a framework.

Comment: @BDL I did not intend the use of the word framework to mean a 3rd party library.  Would changing that word improve the question?

Comment: At the heart of it, your question is about how to time the relative performance of your solutions to determine how they scale and which the best ones are for a given situation. The "motivation" section makes it sound like a meta question, and the "question" section makes it sound like a resource request. With the right edits, you should be able to fix both.

Comment: Note you could probably avoid it being off topic by phrasing it as "How can I test time for panda and numpy solutions" so that a framework recommendation would be an acceptable answer, but you're not explicitly requesting an off-site resource.

Comment: I dislike the word of choice if your goal was to lay down some guidelines on good ways to compare different results during numpy/pandas testing. the word "framework" to me would imply a tool/library recommendation

Comment: @piRSquared: I think the question can be edited into shape. How about "Which techniques exist to measure the runtime of methods in pandas?"? If you edit it now, please make sure not to invalidate any already existing answers.

Comment: I'm happy to edit the question.  Seems clear that we(royal) reserve the term "framwork" to mean something other than what I intended.  I'll correct that.

Comment: It is not just the word. Read the comments by [cs95](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385779/is-my-question-off-topic#comment701569_385779) and [Davy M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385779/is-my-question-off-topic#comment701570_385779) again; they are asking you to reformulate your question to ask how to do the task at hand, not ask for a pre-made solution to the task, irrespective of the word "framework".

Comment: @HereticMonkey let me fixing the word be the beginning.  I'm still processing the rest.

Comment: Just a warning that only your first edit will put the question in the reopen queue for others to determine whether it's worth reopening.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ahh, thank you.  I'll process more quickly then (-:

Comment: Gotta be careful in editing stuff like that out because it invalidates answers, but in this case there's not a giant list of answers that's focused on that part. Since the answers can stand with minor tweaks to remove the old off-topic parts, I voted to reopen

Comment: Project spam is never not a problem, recommendation questions often invite it.  A thumbs-up from the OP tends to help making it more credible.  But where is the signal when the bounty is started *three minutes* after the answer is posted??  Nobody can evaluate a tool or library for fitness that fast.  This was the right call from the moderator.

Comment: @HansPassant that is a fair point.  Do you think it is strong enough of a point to trump the edits?  I'm not making an argument.  That's a legit question.

Comment: I think you have a credibility problem that a moderator can help you with.

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate you jumping in but I don't understand what you mean by "you have a credibility problem".  I'm not sure if you're implying that there is a problem with my credibility or that there exists an issue regarding the credibility of the bounty or something else entirely. Maybe your suggestion of help from a mod implies that you'd rather not wade further.  But your comment concerns me and I'm just wondering what you meant.